# HTML to detect if a qr code is scanned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I meant is that there is a QR code rendered in your page and you can scan it using a scanner in your let's say Iphone. HTML will detect that the QR code rendered is scanned and you can trigger something in javascript like an alert or redirect. Is this currently possible?

The QR Code is from wechat and once it is scanned, a payment will be transact

Comment: It all depends on what the qr code includes. If it is an Link to your website and the user click on it you can track if it is used. Otherwise if it's not for ur website I would say no.

Comment: Also the app will show the user if the code was scanned or not. If you only want client side notification I do not see the point of the page with the QR reacting. If it is not your own site that loads in the QR app, then unless you can put code on that site, then you cannot do anything on the page with the QR. There is no "onscanned" possible unless the screen with the QR code has a camera or is otherwise connected with the device reading the code

Comment: @DestinatioN, the QR code is scanned will transact a payment

Answer (score 2):

i think if you own the link page, you can set some message in the QRCODE link.

like this:
QRCODE set link = http://xxx.xxx/yourPage.html?fromQRcode

so you can track the "?fromQRcde" in the page.

```
var qrCode = '?fromQRcode';
var check = location.search;
if ( qrCode == check ) {
    //dosomething
}
```

or use "#fromQRcode" and location.hash

so, in the same page maybe you can do like this:

```
var qrCode = '#fromQRcode';
var check = location.hash;
if ( qrCode == check ) {
    alert('its scanned !')
    //window.open to some where or something
}
```

---

update my think

i not do this before, maybe you can think about this solution:

#### 1.html -get QRcode from backend API and show it

(1)in the same time, database to keep the API message,
maybe like order001, so you have

|order_no|scanner_yn|

|order001|n         |

(2)set somecode to send backend check scanner_yn, like

```
function checkScannerYn(){
    //do some request to get scanner_yn status
}
//set some timefunction to check that
setInterval(function ,3000)
//and when get right reponse or time out to close
```

#### 2. user scan the QRcode

will send the messate "order001" to backend, 
then backend to do update make the scanner_yn = 'y'

#### 3.front-end javascript get backend reponse 'y' then do you want to do!

sorry for my english and hope help

---

Comment: I don't really understand the hash part.. How will that detect if the QRcode was scanned? Simply put it this,, a QR code is rendered via `img` tag. The Image URL came from an API return.. I will scan the QR code to do some payment and once scanned I want to trigger a Javascript code

Comment: add one, maybe you can search "webSocket" <<

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you would need to have the QR code as unique for that instance of the page.  So each page load would generate a new QR code.  Then when the user scans it in, the mobile device would set a flag in the database to indicate that it has been scanned / payed.

You can then use   [MS SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) to detect the change in the database and to show a message to the user or change the screen.

I don't want to write the code for you but this would work i think

Answer (score -3):

In my theory it is possible. Since QR Code is a URL when scanned it will open the browser and load the page. In the page loaded there you can place a trigger that will notify the page with QR Code that the site was loaded.

Comment: since it is a theory this could not be a complete solution. This can be a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16081048)